# Why is Rails generating incorrect SQL for an order by clause?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why is Rails 3.2.14 generating an incorrect order by clause for this relationship? What is going on here?

> 2.0.0p247 :306 > u.comments.order(created_at: :desc)
>
> Refinery::Groups::Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `refinery_groups_comments`.* FROM `refinery_groups_comments` WHERE `refinery_groups_comments`.`user_id` = 56 ORDER BY '---\n:created_at: :desc\n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 3.2 and older, `order` expects a string:

```
u.comments.order("created_at desc")
```

The `order(created_at: :desc)` style was added in 4.0.

Comment: Is that something new in Rails 4? The syntax that I used? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: Huh, I guess so. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/active_record_querying.html#ordering